# Redirecting all request to a layout page without .htaccess

Tags: php, templating

I hear that creating a single layout page helps maintainability, I am new and about to implement this but am confused about something.
If am correct, a file will serve as the layout file requiring header.php and footer.php, and all request to the server will have to pass through this one file, I also learnt from https://alistapart.com/article/succeed that redirecting to this layout page will require editing the .htaccess file. My question is what if I don't want to edit the .htaccess file and include a code in all my content pages to redirect all  request to the layout file?

Comment: Google search engine friendly (sef). This explains how you make a single entry point for your site. This is a key building block for designing MVC websites.

Comment: thanks Tim, didn't find what I wanted though. I edited the question, I totally misrepresented what i had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend this approach, but I think what you're looking for is this:

On every page, immediately start out with output buffering. When you're done with your page, capture the output buffer in a variable. Turn off output buffering, then include your "layout" page that prints out that variable in between your header and footer HTML.

You'd be better served to learn mvc, though.

To find info on buffering, go to php site and look up ob_start.

Comment: I took your advice @Tim Morton but instead of including layout in every page I redirected all request to my index.php that contains my header and footer  and from the url supplied by the user I import and render the right page, the problem is that I started using .htaccess to rewrite url and then I ran into the problem of knowing the right file to import from the rewritten url so I asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868700/importing-the-right-file-when-im-rewriting-url-with-htaccess, I'll apprecite it if youncan help me.

Comment: I think you're taking the better approach, that is, redirecting all traffic to index.php.  For your .htaccess, look up tutorials on search engine friendly urls.