# Importing the right file when I'm rewriting url with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, import, url-rewriting

I made all request to my site pass trough one `index.php` file, if a user enters `www.example.com/products/20` I want my `index.php` file to import and render the file `/products/index.php` and then still be able to use `product_id=20` parameter. Each time I try to access `www.example.com/products/20` my `index.php` file seems to try to import `/products/31` which does not exist instead of `/products/index.php`.Am rewriting my url with .htaccess is there any way I can import the right page from this url (i.e `example.com/products/20`)?

Comment: Can you provide more details, because the question is unclear now.

Comment: Hello @Neodan, I just edited the question

Comment: Are you wanting to access one page from both `/products/20` and `index.php?product_id=20`? Also, please post your current .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Identifying your requirements

You have product records.  To view the 20th record, you need to pass product_id=20 to your script. To do that, you can either pass it in a query string `?product_id=20` or you can craft a search engine friendly url `/product/20`.  The latter requires url rewriting, usually in `.htaccess`.

Don't get confused-- `.htaccess` does not *create* the search engine friendly url (SEF); it *interprets* it and passes control to some page, ie, `/index.php`.

There are a multitude of tutorials on how to craft `.htaccess` to do this; generally it will look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?topic=$1
```

In your case, you would simply substitute `^product` for `^topic` and `?product_id` for `?topic`.  Oh, and change the regex to `[0-9]`

### What will this accomplish?

Now, when a request that comes in as /product/{someNumber}, mod_rewrite will translate that to `/index.php?product_id={someNumber}`.  So if you type `www.example.com/product/20` or `www.example.com/index.php?product_id=20`, they will both go to the same script.

Note: only URIs matching `product` at the beginning will be affected.  If you typed in `www.example.com/users/20` then the web server would look for an index file in `{documentRoot}/users/20`

### Using index.php

For all URIs starting with `/product`, you can now use index.php as a controller.  In other words, you can use the parameters passed in to determine what the script does from there-- what logic to load, what views to use, etc.

In this example, it's pretty simple; everything coming to index.php will be a product view.

```
<?php
require("../views/header.php");
$query = "select * from products where product_id = ?";
// do your database call and print out results
require("../views/footer.php");
```

note, I always have component parts in directories NOT in the documentRoot path (../views/).  This way, they are inaccessible via URL.

### But what about www.example.com/

Yep, it will try to print out a product page with no product id.  So if you want to have something other than a product page on your index page, just change your .htaccess file to point to some other filename.

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/$ my_product_display_page.php?product_id=$1
```

### More dynamic pages

You aren't limited to just products.  Say you want users, too. Just add more parameters.

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9])$ my_simple_controller.php?action=$1&value=$2
```

and in my_controller.php,

```
require("../views/header.php");
switch($action) {
  case 'product':
    // display product
    break;
  case 'user':
    // display user
    break;
}
require("../views/footer.php");
```

Now, everything that starts with /page/product will display a product, and /page/user will display a user.

Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction.